# CoffeeScript: calculate parse tree (like coffee -n) in a program

Tags: coffeescript, parse-tree

Is there a way to compute the CoffeeScript parse tree of a program (provided as a string) inside CoffeeScript without calling an external program?

For example, let's say I have a string 'square=(n)->n*n' inside a CoffeeScript program.  I want to get the same output as storing this string in a file `square.coffee` and calling on the command line `coffee -n square.coffee` --- but without creating another process:

```
Block
  Assign
    Value "square"
    Code
      Param "n"
      Block
        Op *
          Value "n"
          Value "n"
```

Please, provide with your solution a link to documentation how to interpret the resulting data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look in [the source](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/blob/master/src/command.coffee#L175): the `-n` flag invokes `(require 'coffee-script).nodes`. The result is a syntax tree which corresponds to [grammar.coffee](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/grammar.html) and would be interpreted with [nodes.coffee](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/nodes.html).

So this:

```
(require 'coffee-script').nodes 'square = (n)->n*n'
```

Will give you a syntax tree. Before you print it, you could use its `toString` method to get the same output as the `coffee` CLI.

For the filesystem operations, just use node's `readFile` or `readFileSync` from the `fs` library:

```
{readFileSync} = require 'fs'
{nodes}        = require 'coffee-script'

nodes readFileSync('squares.coffee').toString()
```